# java.lang.IllegalStateException при выполнении setPixel

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, imageview

Считываю изображение из галереи, далее помещаю его в ImageView, все корректно. Однако, когда я пытаюсь изменить пиксель, то получаю данную ошибку. Притом данная ошибка возникает тогда, когда выбирается изображение не с камеры, а, например, из скриншотов. Если брать из загрузок, то работает корректно. С чем это может быть связано? Само изображение хранится в Bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из документации [`Bitmap.setPixel(int, int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel(int,%20int,%20int)) :

> Throws
>    `IllegalStateException`  if the bitmap is not mutable
>    `IllegalArgumentException`   if x, y are outside of the bitmap's bounds.

У Вас битмап неизменяемый, создать изменяемую копию можно методом:

[`Bitmap mutable = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean))